# Manage own fork of Vim plugins with Vundle

Tags: github, vim, pull-request, git-fork, vundle

I use Vundle as plug-in manager in Vim and it happens that I want to make modifications to some plug-in to correct bugs or to implement personal changes.

What I do in general is

1. fork the original repo
2. edit the `.vimrc` file and change the line `Plugin 'original-repo'` to `Plugin 'my-fork'`, run `:so %` and then `:PluginInstall`
3. make changes and commit
4. push to my fork
5. send a PR

At this point the PR can be accepter or rejected. In the former case, everything's ok. What about the latter case?

What I mean is that in general I can decide to keep the unaccepted edit in my fork (I've just committed it, after all), as well as in the local branch (that is, I keep `Plugin 'my-fork'` in my `.vimrc` file), since I consider this edit to be important to me, for some reason.
On the other hand, I don't want my fork to get old just because I diverged by one or a few commits; that is, I still want to have my fork include new commits of the original repo.
In addition, I want to be still able to send PR of other commits I can do, paying attention to the PR best practice of sending PRs from a synced fork.

I can imagine what the tools are fit for purpose, i.e.

- the web for creating the fork and send PRs
- `git` to manage different branches of the local fork
- `Vundle` to manage Vim plugins

which I'm already using.

So the question is: what is the workflow I should follow to manage Vim plugins to which I can possibly participate with PRs of commits (and I obviously can't know in advance which PRs are accepted and which are rejected)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GitHub as whole guide devoted to [working with forks](https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-forks/).

In short:

1. you define a new remote repository that points to the original,
2. you fetch and merge from that "upstream" remote repository to keep your repository in sync.

Comment: First of all, thank you for the answer, I will read the guide. What about the plugins? Do you suggest that in my `.vimrc` I keep `Plugin 'name/repo'` lines for plugins which I do not edit/collaborate to/etc and `Plugin 'myname/myfork'` for the plugins I do edit/...?

Comment: Yes. That's exactly how to do it.